# Need REGEX help returning multiple lines between keywords

Tags: python, regex, string, multiline

I've straggle with this for two days and finally dare to ask.

Here is my data (file):

```
EXH;2;20180514103023+00;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_92_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_92_12345;;;;;;LOS_92_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_93_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_93_12345;;;;;;LOS_93_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_96_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_96_12345;;;;;;LOS_96_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_97_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_97_12345;;;;;;LOS_97_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
EXT;
```

I'd like to get from regex 4 blocks (4 matches) like:

```
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_92_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_92_12345;;;;;;LOS_92_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
```

On each of match, I'll apply some further regex. But for now, I can not make a regex to return those matches.

Here is what I tried:

```
(TSH;FI(?:.*?\r?\n?)*(?<=TSH;))+
```

But this one returns only 2 matches (each second) probably because it consumes each "TSH;" of the block after the match.

```
(TSH;(?:.*?\r?\n?)*)+(?<=\nTSH;)
```

This one finds 4 "TSH;" but not the full block.

Help needed :)
P.S. will be used in Python

Comment: Perhaps this is actually what you need: https://regex101.com/r/v2mli7/1

Comment: @nhahtdh I deliberately excluded `TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;` from the match because in the desired output it only goes up to `TSV;3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
(?s)^TSH;.*?Z01;(?=\nTSH|\nTSV;4)
```

- `(?s)` `re.DOTALL` option.
- `^TSH;` Match substring `TSH;` at start of string.
- `.*?` Match anything lazily.
- `Z01;` Match substring `Z01;`.
- `(?=\nTSH|\nTSV;4)`. Positive lookahead for either `TSH` or `TSV;4`.

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/8cbS4o/3).

In Python you can use:

```
print(re.findall(r'^TSH;.*?Z01;(?=\nTSH|\nTSV;4)',mystr,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE))
```

Comment: UnbearableLightness thank you a lot! 
Now that I'm trying this out I notice that I've put wrong data in. I missed 1 line in raw data and there for missed 1 line in match. I'll try to correct it now. Perhaps that makes regex bit shorter.
Because what I want as match is starts with TSH; and ends before next TSH or EXT
Which means amount of lines in match doesn't matter!

Comment: @user2997497 Please update the open post with the correct information. I will be happy to edit my answer to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Never dare to ask if struggle longer. I bet you are looking for this:

```
TSH(?:\n|.)+?(?=\nTSH|\nEXT|\nTSV;4)
```

Demo on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uHM4nM/4) and explanation here:

- `TSH` is obvious, matches literally
- `(?:\n|.)` is a non-capturing group of characters. Because `.` matches any character (except for line terminators), you have to add a new line character `\n`.
- `(?:\n|.)+?` match at least one character from the group described above
- `(?=\nTSH|\nEXT|\nTSV;4)` until one of the terminating conditions is reached. Note the `\n`, otherwise, an empty line will be matched as well.

Comment: The desired output does not contain `TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;`. You are matching too much.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I wouldn't use a regular expression at all for this job.

It seems much easier to just split by `TSH` then clean it up later.

So if the data is in `data`, we can do something like this:

```
blocks = [ "TSH" + block for block in data.split("TSH") ]
```

The first block is bogus so get rid of it:

```
blocks = blocks[1:]
```

And the last block has that extra `"EXT;\n"`, so clean that up too:

```
blocks = blocks[-1] = blocks[-1][:-len("EXT;\n")]
```

And that's it, you're done.

Of course, that's assuming that `TSH` can't appear in the middle of your data. If it does, you can split the data by newlines, look which lines begin with `TSH`, then use those indexes to carve up your data.

Here's a real nasty one-liner that does that:

```
["\n".join(data.split()[i:j]) for i, j in zip(*(lambda a, b: (a, next(b) and b))(*itertools.tee(itertools.chain(( i for i, line in enumerate(data.split()) if line.startswith("TSH")), (len(data.split()),)))))]
```

Comment: I see what are you saying, and I did have my thoughts about it also. And in the end I thought that I either to full parser of the file python programming or do everything via regex. And Plan A was regex. And now that I got it working I'm actually pretty happy that Plan A was what it was. Mainly because if my "question" to the file changes - I do not modify parsing, but just change regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected test data:

```
EXH;2;20180514103023+00;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_92_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_92_12345;;;;;;LOS_92_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_93_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_93_12345;;;;;;LOS_93_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_96_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_96_12345;;;;;;LOS_96_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_97_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_97_12345;;;;;;LOS_97_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
EXT;
```

with an expression like

```
(?s)^TSH;.*?Z01;(?=\nTSH|\nEXT)
```

I do get matched like I wanted blocks of TSH.... records like:

```
TSH;FI__REPLACEMGA_LOS_92_12345;1;1;HOUR;kWh;24;201805120000+00;201805130000+00;LOS_92_12345;;;;;;LOS_92_12345;;;
TSV;1;201805120000+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;2;201805120100+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;3;201805120200+00;0.000000;Z01;
TSV;4;201805120300+00;0.000000;Z01;
```

Big thanks to UnbearableLightness

Comment: You are welcome. Yes my understanding from the OP was that you wanted to exclude the fourth line from the match.

Comment: I wanted just to shrink data (cause real file has 24 lines) and made that mistake with extra line. And your sharp eye did focus on it :)